# unable to call a component function from my service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I am using observables to call my component function from inside my service here is my service code :

```
  private trades = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  tradeMethodCalled$ = this.trades.asObservable();

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getAllTrades() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log('here');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.get('http://localhost:50005/api/trading/trades',{
     headers: headers
   }).pipe(map((res : any)=>res.json()))
   .subscribe(
    (res) => {
     this.payload = res[0].state.data;
     console.log('success');
     console.log(this.payload);
     this.trades.next();
    }
   );
   }
```

Here is my component code

```
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
trades;
party;
  constructor(public service: CordaContentService,private routes : ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.service.tradeMethodCalled$.subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log(this.trades + "here");
        routes.params.subscribe(val => {
          this.trades=this.service.gettrades();
          console.log(this.trades);
    })
    });
  }
```

what am i doing wrong?
My component function isn't getting triggered , i am using angular 6.Please provide a clear solution

Comment: Are you calling `getAllTrades` anywhere in your app ? Doesn't seem so. I think you are doing something fundamentally wrong. Could you explain, please, what are you trying to achieve ? From what I see I would strongly suggest moving `route.params.subscribe` higher. I would also not write `getAllTrades` that way, rather make it return an observable with the response instead of all of this weird stuff that is happening there. Also since the code here is rather simple I would advice you to create some example on stackblitz so it would be easier to potentially debug your code.

Comment: You need send some value:this.trades.next(this.payload). Anyway. you must use httpClient -not the old and deprecated http- and re-think your service . In general "the services return observables and we subscribe to the observables in the components". This make more easy use Rxjs operators like switchMap, forkJoin, etc.

Comment: I am calling the gettrades method from the ngonit body in my app.component.ts and I have done the same thing in angular 2 may be it is due to the version you think?

Comment: Any examples https://stackoverflow.com/users/8558186/eliseo?